# Is there a natural isomorphism?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a real vector space,$V_{\Bbb C}=V\otimes\Bbb C=V\oplus iV$ be its complexification

Is there a natural isomorphism between $Hom_{\Bbb R}(V,\Bbb C)$ and $(V_{\Bbb C})^\ast$?

It seems quite simple,but how to build a explicit formula?

Any hints or references would be appreciated as well!

Answer (score 2):

In general, the scalar extension on a vector space has the following universal property : let $V$ be a $K$-vector space, and $L/K$ be a field extension ; then for any $L$-vector space $W$ there is a canonical isomorphism $Hom_K(V,W)\simeq Hom_L(V_L,W)$ (as $K$-vector spaces).

If $f\in Hom_K(V,W)$, then the corresponding $f_L\in Hom_L(V_L,W)$ is given by $f_L(x\otimes \lambda) = \lambda f(x)$.

So in your case, taking $K=\mathbb{R}$, $L=\mathbb{C}$ and $W=\mathbb{C}$, you get a canonical isomorphism $Hom_\mathbb{R}(V,\mathbb{C})\simeq (V_\mathbb{C})^*$ as you wanted.